# Loading Tab Delimited Key-Value data into Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, apache-pig

Is there a good way to load key value pairs, tab delimited data where each row has a different keys depending on the value of one of the keys?

Data example:

```
type:A     field1:valueA1     field2:valueA2     field3:valueA3   
type:A     field1:valueA1     field2:valueA2     field3:valueA3
type:B     field1:valueB1     field4:valueB4
```

Any Pig, Hive or HBase Solution will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the types in different HBase Column names and the field:value pairs as hbase rows. (Unique field key: value)

Comment: Could you please provide a snippet? I have never performed any bulk-data load into HBase table using any Data set. So, I'm not sure how to achieve this.